# Finding the total cost less than the average SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to database. And I'm trying to learn it. I understand the basics of it but it's when questions like these pop up do I get dumbfounded. I have attached the logical model, the question and what I have tried below.

[image]

The questions is this:
List those completed charters where the total cost is less than the average total cost for all
charters. The total cost for a charter is obtained by multiplying the charter cost per hour with
the actual duration obtained from the leg actual departure and actual arrival times. A
completed charter means all legs have been flown.
Show charter number, client number, client lastname, client firstname, total charter cost. The
total charter cost should be rounded to two decimal digits and displayed with a $ symbol
e.g. $1234.56
For this question, if either client name is empty '-' should be displayed.
The listing should be displayed in the descending order of total charter cost.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT
chart.charter_nbr,
client_nbr,
client_lname,
client_fname,
chart.charter_cost_per_hour * (leg.cl_ata - leg.cl_atd) as TotalCharterCost

FROM
mh.charter chart
JOIN mh.client cli ON chart.client_nbr = cli.client_nbr
JOIN mh.charter_leg leg ON chart.charter_nbr = leg.charter_nbr

WHERE 
TotalCharterCost < (SELECT
                        AVG(cost)
                    FROM
                        mh.charter chart1
                        JOIN mh.charter_leg leg1 ON chart1.charter_nbr = leg1.charter_nbr
                    WHERE
                        cost = (leg1.cl_ata - leg1.cl_atd) * chart1.charter_cost_per_hour
                    );
```

Can anyone guide me or help me with this? I'm still learning and very new to databases

Comment: Hello Rana, welcome to stackoverflow. A good place to start is this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . In your case giving an answer is a challenge because... you provided the data model (as a picture) and a sql query but... no scripts to create your tables and no script to create a minimal data set.
At first glance this syntax is incorrect:  ```...TotalCharterCost < (SELECT ...```

Answer (score 0):

Columns aliases ("TotalCharterCost") cannot be used on WHERE clauses.
AVG statement is also incorrect.
Run your queries individually first, before trying to putting them all together:

```
SELECT
chart.charter_nbr,
client_nbr,
client_lname,
client_fname,
chart.charter_cost_per_hour * (leg.cl_ata - leg.cl_atd) as TotalCharterCost

FROM
mh.charter chart
JOIN mh.client cli ON chart.client_nbr = cli.client_nbr
JOIN mh.charter_leg leg ON chart.charter_nbr = leg.charter_nbr

WHERE 
chart.charter_cost_per_hour * (leg.cl_ata - leg.cl_atd) < (SELECT
                        AVG( chart1.charter_cost_per_hour * (leg1.cl_ata - leg1.cl_atd) )
                    FROM
                        mh.charter chart1
                        JOIN mh.charter_leg leg1 ON chart1.charter_nbr = leg1.charter_nbr                        
                    );
```